# Graphs with disjoint edge sets

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Consider a fixed set of vertices $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m\}$ and a family of graphs $G_1, G_2, \ldots, G_n$ on these vertices such that no two graphs share an edge. In other words, if $E(G_i)$ is the edge set of $G_i$, then for every $i \neq j$ we have $E(G_i) \cap E(G_j) = \emptyset$.

Is there a name for such families of graphs? Have these been studied at all? For instance, I'm imagining that you can prove bounds on things such as maximal vertex degrees in terms of $m$ and $n$. Conversely, there may be conditions under which you can show that $E(G_i) \cap E(G_j) \neq \emptyset$ for some $i,j$.

Much of this may be elementary, but having never worked in graph theory I am completely unfamiliar with the existing literature, and so in an effort to avoid reinventing the wheel, I'm posting this question.